# Rails Controller in Folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to change the structure of my rails project from :

```
|- controllers
  |- club_controller.rb
  |- club_accounting.rb
  ...
```

to :

```
|- controllers
  |- club
    |- club_controller.rb
    |- club_accounting.rb
  ...
```

but I don't know how to declare it, if I have to change routes or other files.

Here my routes :

```
# Clubs routes
  resources :clubs do
    get '/club_accounting', to: 'club_accounting#index', as: 'club_accounting_index'
    post '/club_accounting', to: 'club_accounting#create', as: 'club_accounting_create'
    delete '/club_accounting/:id', to: 'club_accounting#delete', as: 'club_accounting_delete'
    get '/members', to: :members, as: 'club_members'
    post '/members/add_member', to: :add_member, as: 'add_member'
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have this structure

```
|- controllers
  |- club
    |- clubs_controller.rb
    |- club_accountings.rb
```

Your `controller classes` should look like below

```
#clubs_controller.rb
Class Club::ClubsController < ApplicationController
```

and

```
#club_accountings_controller.rb
Class Club::ClubAccountingsController < ApplicationController
```

And your `routes` should look like

```
namespace :clubs do
  resources :clubs
  resources :club_accountings
  #your other routes here
end
```

**Note:** Controller names should be **`plural`**,not **`singular`**.It is against the **`Rails conventions`**.

Hope it helps!